# Remove unused flag-icon-css images from dist directory

Tags: angular, webpack, ng-build

Angular 7 app uses flag-icon-css.

`ng build --prod` creates dist directory that contains all flag icon images, even though I use only 5-7 images for now ( I will use more when the app grows ).

This adds a lot of unnecessary weight to the project.

On flag-icon-css github page there are instructions on how to remove unused images by editing `flag-icon-list.less`, but that didn't do the trick.
https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css#development

Is there a way to exclude unused flag icon images from the dist directory?

Answer (score 0):

I imported flag icons in `styles.css` from node_modules:

`@import 'flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css'`

Instead of importing from node_modules, I moved `flag-icon.css` to `src/assets/css`:

`@import 'flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css';`

Commented out unused icons.
Run build again, `dist` directory will contain only images that are used.

Comment: This actually works, it doesn't make much sense to do that, but... hey. It works.